# Bash script to check if a file on FTP was modified in last 24 hrs(1day) and download only if it has changed

Tags: bash, ftp

I have access to an FTP server where clients are uploading an updated file twice a week. I have to write a bash script to check if the file (I know the name of file) was modified in last 24hrs: if yes, then I need to download that file.

I am able to normally download a file from FTP using a bash script, but I am not sure how to check the last modified time in FTP.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to download the remote file if it is newer than the local file?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases FTP `ls` command is linked to server `ls` command. So you should try

```
ls -l <filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is probably with `curl`, using the [`-z`/`--time-cond`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-z) option:

> (HTTP/FTP) **Request a file that has been modified later than the given time and date**, or one that has been modified before that time. The  can be all sorts of date strings or if it doesn't match any internal ones, it is taken as a filename and tries to get the modification date (mtime) from  instead. See the curl_getdate(3) man pages for date expression details.

The accepted date formats are specified in [`curl_getdate` docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_getdate.html), but it suffices to say the usual English-natural [RFC-822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) format is supported, which is also supported in `date` util via `-R`/`--rfc-2822` option.

We can calculate the date/time of the cut-off timestamp 24 hour ago with a relative `date` string:

```
$ date -R -d '24 hours ago'
Mon, 25 Sep 2017 17:30:49 +0200
```

and supply that value to `curl`:

```
curl 'ftp://server/file' --time-cond "$(date -R -d '24 hour ago')"
```

To save the output directly to a local file (and not output it to stdout), use the `--output filename` option, and to suppress the progress output, use the `-s` option.